# ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile when setting Java PATH

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, path

Could you explain me why on this site - https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml is instruction which says: Edit the startup file (~/.bashrc) and then Load the startup file . /.profile. I don' t know how it works. Why should I reload profile instead of bashrc? I tried to look for answer, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you find this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/432527/230364) useful?

Comment: Is this on your local development machine, or a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `~/.profile`, it may exists the code snippet like this:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Then it will reload the `~/.bashrc` file. But you just execute `. ~/.bashrc` file will be ok also.